# Can someone illustrate the difference between Native Mode Reports Using SharePoint Web Parts (SSRS) and Reports with SharePoint 2.0 Web Parts?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I was trying to see what are the advantages on using either a SSRS or a  Reports with SharePoint 2.0 Web Parts. Or are there any specific scenarios we have to use either of them?

Comment: Are you seriously asking about WSS 2.0? To confirm, which OS are you running that SP server on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be wrong but I think this might be along the lines of what you're looking for.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2737/sql-server-reporting-services-vs-performancepoint-services/